# Como pegar os parágrafos de um trecho de texto selecionado?

Tags: javascript

Imagine que o trecho entre chaves seja um texto selecionado com o mouse...

Que capturei com:

`window.getSelection().toString();`

```
<p> <--- [pegar daqui]
Meu texto selecionado {está aqui
</p>
<p>
E aqui} também
</p> <--- [até aqui]
```

Como eu poderia extrair os parágrafos de uma HTML pegando começo e o final dos parágrafos onde ocorreu uma seleção?

Eu tentei isso, mas ele não captura o que existe de fato, ele apenas faz uma cópia dos containers do tipo parágrafo para dentro de um container:

```
function containerSelection(sel) {
     if (sel.rangeCount) {
        var container = document.createElement('div');
            container.setAttribute('id', 'check_selection');
            container.setAttribute('style', 'display:none');

           for (var i = 0, len = sel.rangeCount; i < len; ++i) {
                container.appendChild(sel.getRangeAt(i).cloneContents());
           }

          document.body.appendChild(container); 
     }
}
```

Ou seja, em vez do método pegar isso:

```
<div id="check_selection">
 <p>Meu texto selecionado {está aqui
    </p>
    <p>
    E aqui} também
    </p>
</div>
```

Ele está pegando assim:

```
<div id="check_selection">
 <p>{está aqui</p>
 <p>E aqui}</p>
</div>
```

> Sei que esse atributo pega o pai, porém, está pegando o container de onde estão os parágrafos: `range.commonAncestorContainer`